# Generate Typescript .d.ts file for spin.js

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to generate a .d.ts file for spin.js library (http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/).

How to proceed on that?

Comment: For a guide on writing your own definitions, take a look at [this](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files).

Comment: Actually, it looks like someone has already done the work for you: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/spin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already written

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/spin/spin.d.ts

use

```
new Spinner({lines: 3, radius: 5}).spin(document.getElementById("test"));
```